# concatenate range of cells in RC style notation vba macros

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

I am performing a linear interpolation for my class project. I have created an interpolation function and have to perform calculation dynamically, as the number of column varies for each problem. So, I have retrieved the value for last column(ltr) and trying to concatenate it with R1C1 format. But it doesn’t work. Could you please suggest some idea, how do workaround for this issue.
Please find below the following code:

```
Private Sub TrialCheck_Click() 
    Dim lrt As Double 
    With ActiveSheet 
         'retrives last column i.e lrt = 447
        lrt = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row 
    End With 
    Range("I3").Value = Range("F3").Value * Range("B3").Value 
    Range("I58").Value = Range("F" & lrt).Value * Range("B58").Value 
     'MacroR
     'following works as 447 is hardcoded
     'Range("I4").Value = _
    "=(LinInterp(RC[-8],R4C[-4]:R447C[-4],R4C[-3]:R447C[-3])*RC[-7])" 
     'following code doesn't concatenate value of lrt
    Range("I4").Value = _ 
    "=(LinInterp(RC[-8],R4C[-4]:R&lrt&C[-4],R4C[-3]:R&lrt&C[-3])*RC[-7])" 
    Range("J4").Select 

    Range("I4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("I4:I57"), Type:=xlFillDefault 
    Range("I4:I57").Select 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do string concatenation

```
"string" & lrt & "string" & lrt & "string"

Range("I4").Value = _ 
"=(LinInterp(RC[-8],R4C[-4]:R" & lrt & "C[-4],R4C[-3]:R" & lrt & "C[-3])*RC[-7])"
```